# Cannot install homebrew on macOS 14 pre-release

Tags: macos, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools, macos-sonoma

I have a fresh Macbook Pro M2 running MacOS 14 pre-release.

I attempt to install homebrew from the bash-line on https://brew.sh

At this point:

```
==> Installing the Command Line Tools (expect a GUI popup):
xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools
Press any key when the installation has completed.
```

... a dialog pops up (likely behind your terminal if you're not seeing it) to guide thru installation of `XCode CommandLine Tools` (prerequisite for brew).

However the download fails:

[image]

After I hit a key in Terminal, output concludes:

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply install `XCode CommandLine Tools` from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command

I installed the latest beta, and it works!